# How to prevent Rate limit attack?

Tags: c#, .net, ip, rate-limiting, real-ip

I'm using AspNetCoreRateLimit in .net6, when X-Real-IP change in request then rate limit reset.

```json
  "IpRateLimitOptions": {
    "EnableEndpointRateLimiting": false,
    "DisableRateLimitHeaders": true,
    "StackBlockedRequests": false,
    "RealIpHeader": "X-Real-IP",
    "ClientIdHeader": "X-ClientId",
    "EndpointWhitelist": [ "get:/js/*", "get:/lib/*", "get:/fonts/*", "get:/favicon.ico" ],
    "HttpStatusCode": 429,
    "QuotaExceededMessage": "API calls quota exceeded",
    "GeneralRules": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "1s",
        "Limit": 5
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "15m",
        "Limit": 100
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "12h",
        "Limit": 1000
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "*",
        "Period": "7d",
        "Limit": 10000
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: you do not want the IP based rate limit?

Comment: yes I want the IP based rate limit, but now if attacker change x-real-ip in header of request then my rate limit reset